# Tryin to conver cookie.txt file to .dat file. To open this file in pickel for chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pickle

I downloaded cookie file from Dolphin Anti. The file downloaded without any file extension. In file exist `list []` and `dict {}` inside the list. I've tried to convert `txt` file to `dat` with pickle.

```
cookie_text_file = r'C:\Path\my_cookies'

output_dat_file = r'C:\Users\under\Desktop\Python\Web3\Selenium\my_cookies.dat'

with open(cookie_text_file, 'r') as file:
    cookie_data = file.read()

with open(output_dat_file, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(cookie_data, file)
```

After I'm trying to load to my main script
And all the time getting errors to load cookie file.

Also you can check on the screenshot TXT file and print of `dat` file.

```
cookies_path = r'C:\Path\my_cookies.dat'
with open(cookies_path, 'rb') as f:
    cookies = pickle.load(f)
    print(typy(cookies))
```

the print: `class 'str'`
so I guess the convert not good
because it should by : `<class 'list'>`

I tried to 'wb' write cookies from chromedriver and then to load 'rb' with pickle and its worked well.

Please how can I load txt file to pickle or to the webdriver?
or how to convert in right way txt file to `dat` file?

```
import pickle

cookie_text_file = r'C:\Users\under\Desktop\Python\Web3\Selenium\Koiner 1'

output_dat_file = r'C:\Users\under\Desktop\Python\Web3\Selenium\my_cookies.dat'

with open(cookie_text_file, 'r') as file:
    cookie_data = file.read()

with open(output_dat_file, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(cookie_data, file)
```

convert from `txt` to `dat`